# PowerShell shows (base) in front of prompt

Tags: powershell

My PowerShell on Windows 10 started to show the word (base). I did not see this on other machines and it started to happen recently. I'm not sure what I did to cause this and I can't find any information about it. My PowerShell $PROFILE file is empty.

```
Windows PowerShell
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

Loading personal and system profiles took 1083ms.
(base) PS C:\>
```

I see the same in the Package Manager Console in Visual Studio

```
(base) PM>
```

Does anyone know what this means and how can I get rid of it again?

Comment: Did you check **ALL** profiles? `$PROFILE | Format-List -Force` What does `(Get-Command prompt).Definition` return?

Comment: Thank you. That helped. One of the files contained the initialization script for Miniconda. Removing that line or calling `conda deactivate` solves the problem.

Answer (score 2):

As Andy Bochmann commented

The prefix (base) indicated that you are running inside the conda/anaconda environment.

The command "conda deactivate" should bring you back to the standard prompt.